# How to cut a large photo into a grid of smaller photos automatically in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, grids, slices

Is there a way, maybe a script, that would help me cut an image into say 50 images?

I have a massive panorama I would like to print on normal stock photo paper and I am using Photoshop.

The output of this operation needs to be images, not PDFs, not printer. There is still work to be done with each of these cut-outs later.

**How can I slice a large image into many smaller images with an automated, or relatively fast method?**

Comment: Can't you just type the scale into your print dialogue and have it tile to multiple pages? OS X does it. Failing that, do you have InDesign? It'll do it. Tiling is a pretty standard printing feature. No need to cut up the images into parts.

Comment: Thank's, what I actually needed to achieve was to cut the image in 50 images all of them identical in size and with correct side ratio (2:3), then I had to add a border of a very specific width to each side of every cut out image. Then I am sending it for print. I figured how to do it yesterday and had it printed also. It looks great, except the bleed (border) needs to be bigger and I need to find a way to tell the machine operator to not fu*k with my colors and not try to "improve" each photos curve.

Comment: Seems like this question is locked for adding more answers, but it's easy to do with imagemagick, the command line command to cut an image into a 10x10 grid is: convert image.jpg -crop 10%x10% +repage image_%d.jpg

Answer (score 45, accepted):

No need for a script (yet), I found a simple way. Hope it helps someone else too.
If you want all the cutouts / slices to be of same size and cover whole image, resize or crop base image accordingly.

1. Create one big slice, containing the whole image.
2. Right click on the slice icon in the top left corner of the image.
3. Choose Divide Slice and define into how many slices do you want to divide your image, or set the size of each sub-slice.
4. Hit ok.
5. File > Export > Save for web (Legacy) > Save:  Make sure "Save all slices" is selected in the dialog.
6. Profit

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work with massive, got a 1.2GB .tif that i need to split, but the option is disabled.

Answer (score 4):

[ImageSplitter](http://imagesplitter.net/) is the best online tool by which one can cut the image into many slices. Upload the image, click the tab 'Split Image' and set the number of rows and columns you want.

Comment: Hello ruhee, welcome to GD SE. Could you please elaborate on your answer to maybe a paragraph, explaining how to use the web service you mention, and then you can even include a link to the service. It's no-follow but your software may be relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

There's web sites that can do this for you:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiled_printing

Comment: Thanks but the image was about 800MB and those web services usually have space limit, plus you never know what kind of algorithm and compression they use.

Answer (score 0):

You could output a single Photoshop PDF, then use Acrobat to print it on tiled multiple sheets (Print > Page Handling > Page Scaling: Tile All Pages, unless it's changed in the last couple of versions), with cut marks if you wish.

Comment: Unless you're using Acrobat 9 on Max OSX 10.6.8 like I am:  http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6961/indesign-cs4-or-cs5-how-do-i-export-tiles-to-a-pdf

Comment: Hmm,  I'm still on Acrobat 8 on Windows,  so I can only vouch for that version.

Comment: I am sending the photos to be printed so I would have to print to virtual PDF printer, and then export the image from each PDF and add borders :)

Comment: Ah, so your output needs to be a pile of JPGs with blank borders? Might be worth putting that in the Q.

Comment: You're right. I though saying "cut an image into say 75 images" was clear enough, but then I talk about printing it, I(ll edit it.