# Photoshop: How to crop multiple selection and save into separated images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, crop

Take a look on this image:
[image: image example]

My question is how to crop multiple selections at once into images (each square of comic strip). I want to select each frame of the comic and export them as individual images and do multiple exports at once. Do you have any suggestion how can i do this?Sorry, but i don't have any clue how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you want to select each frame of the comic and export them as individual images and do multiple exports at once?

Comment: Yes, Exactly... I updated my question with your contribution.thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is using the **slice tool (C)** in Photoshop. You can press **shift + C** to scroll through those options or hold and click to see more.

Make a selection around each graphic. If you need to move a selection use the **slice selection tool (C)** which is under the same area as the selection tool.

You will then want to go to file - save for web. Make sure to save as images only (you don't need to include HTML).

Comment: This is the solution that @pinha already show in the following url http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7480/how-to-cut-a-large-photo-into-a-grid-of-smaller-photos-automatically-in-photosho

Comment: i just tried the slice, it worked but saved some of the sliced images as .gif and some as .jpeg, even when i initially picked jpeg.
you might wanna watch out for that though.

Answer (score -2):

Are you talking about slices?

The solution to your problem is to use image slicing, which will allow you to save the image, a piece!

How to: http://www.creativebloq.com/adobe/image-slicing-photoshop-61412081

Comment: Could you please provide more of an answer than just a link? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry @Johannes, but I believe the tutorial on the link is short and simple. If you want us to creat a tutorial for all the questions arround here we would spend our lifes doing so!

Comment: Please check also this post, I believe, on the same subject.

http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7480/how-to-cut-a-large-photo-into-a-grid-of-smaller-photos-automatically-in-photosho

Comment: I have look for your links and it helps me a lot. Slice is the solution, i'm wondering if i can save a grid of slice and apply to several psd projects. Thanks @pinha for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you have always the same image size, why not to make it a Photoshop Action :)

Comment: I think you took a step in the right direction by _somewhat_ fleshing out your answer, but let me make clear: "link only" answer is [not welcome on Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/216955) and will be removed.